# CAS server for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, cas

I've implemented **CAS Auth using subfission/cas** package, but **I couldn't** manage to **find** proper instructions for building **a CAS server**.

after some digging, I've found this **reply from subfission**: 'yes, this is an interface for the Jasig CAS client. **You will need to implement a CAS server independently.**'. (https://github.com/subfission/cas/issues/62)

sofar I've tried to read the 'Apereo CAS' documentation, but due to being a newbie, it made me even more confused.

can anyone point me in the right direction? **how can I build a simple CAS server with laravel?**

Comment: There's https://github.com/leo108/php_cas_server that claims to have an implementation of one however last update was 4 years ago so maybe fork it and maintain it yourself to be sure security issues are fixed as you find them

Comment: somebody has already done that (https://github.com/juhedata/laravel_cas_server), 
but I'm getting odd errors like "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target [JuheData\CAS\Contracts\Interactions\UserLogin] is not instantiable while building [JuheData\CAS\Http\Controllers\SecurityController]."

Comment: I have no idea how to use that library but this `BindingResolutionException` can usually be resolved by doing `app()->bind(JuheData\CAS\Contracts\Interactions\UserLogin::class, App\User::class);` assuming your user class implements `UserLogin` (since I think that's required to use it)